# what if i donot specify default in decode in informatica

Tags: decode, informatica, informatica-powercenter

If i don't specify value of default in informatica,what will it consider for default then?

My basic question is

Do both statement work same

DECODE(abc,'XYZ','XZ','OYE','KYA')

DECODE(abc,'XYZ','XZ','OYE','KYA',abc)

Comment: Try it! Use a debugger, for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
Return Value of DECODE

1.First_result if the search finds a matching value. 
2.Default value if the search does not find a matching value. 
3.NULL if you omit the default argument and the search does not find a matching value. 
4. Even if multiple conditions are met, the Data Integration Service returns the first matching result. 
5.If the data contains multibyte characters and the DECODE expression compares string data, the return value depends on the code page and data movement mode of the Data Integration Service.
```

So, in your first statement - NULL will returned if there is no Match.

And in the second stament, it returns the column data if there is no Match